# Update a variant by searching for a custom field value

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I've written a stock import routine that takes data from a CSV, the column I need to match on is a custom field `supplierSku`. I can't find an easy way to search variants for this specifically so am using SQL at the moment, which may be faster but not very elegant. Any suggestions?

```
foreach($stock as $item) {            
    craft()->db->createCommand('UPDATE craft_commerce_variants v JOIN craft_content c ON c.elementId=v.id SET stock=:stock WHERE c.field_supplierSku=:sku')
        ->bindParam(":stock",$item[1])
        ->bindParam(":sku",$item[0])
        ->query();
}
```